# triggering appearance/removal transitions in deeply nested SwiftUI views

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I know that SwiftUI can animate the conditional placement of a view inside another one like so

```swift
if condition {
    MyView().transition(.opacity)
}
```

What does not seem to work, is any nested transition inside `MyView`. So say I have this simplified example:

```swift
struct NestedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("I shall appear with an offset transition").transition(.offset(x: -30))
    }
}

struct OuterView: View {
    let condition: Bool

    var body: some View {
        if condition {
            NestedView().transition(.opacity)
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the `.opacity` transition works when `condition` changes. But the nested `.offset` transition within `NestedView` does not seem to trigger. I could pass in `condition` and add an if there too potentially, but is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think Xcode would apply more than 1 transition to the same content? Do you think making a view stand alone would solve the issue?

Comment: I guess for the same reason other view modifiers "stack on top of each other" in a hierarchy. It also feels very reasonable to want something like this for any reasonably sophisticated animation to compose itself neatly.